# Recommended WPF Calendar

Tags: .net, wpf

What WPF Calendar control would you recommend?  I am looking for something that will let me display a variable amount of weeks potentially spanning multiple months.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft has now released a WPF calendar control.

```
<c:Calendar>
    <c:DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
        <c:CalendarDateRange Start="4/1/2008"  End="4/6/2008"/>
        <c:CalendarDateRange Start="4/14/2008" End="4/17/2008"/>
    </c:DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
</c:Calendar>
<c:DatePicker>
    <c:DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
        <c:CalendarDateRange Start="4/1/2008"  End="4/6/2008"/>
        <c:CalendarDateRange Start="4/14/2008" End="4/17/2008"/>
    </c:DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
</c:DatePicker>
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [windowsclient.net](http://windowsclient.net/SiteFiles/1000/wpfsp1/wpf-35sp1-toolkit/110-1.png))</sub>

- http://www.codeplex.com/wpf
- http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-calendar-datepicker-walkthrough.aspx

Charles Petzold wrote a [good article about customising the WPF calendar control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx) too.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [Kevin's Bag-o-tricks](http://j832.com/BagOTricks/)